# Flutter how to parse data from internet json to get a list of numbers as separate objects

Tags: json, flutter, parsing

I need to download json data from the internet

```
[
{
"day": "Monday:",
"hours": [22, 27]
},
{
"day": "Tuesday :",
"hours": [22, 27]
},
{
"day": "Wednesday",
"hours": [22, 27]
}, 
]
```

I want the data from the "hours" item to be retrieved as separate elements (without square brackets)

Could someone please provide an example ?

I get an error popping up all the time

"flutter _typeerror (type 'string' is not a subtype of type 'map<dynamic, dynamic>'"

```
My current class looks like this 
class DaysList {
  final String days;
  final String hours;

  const DayList({required this.days, required this.hours});

  static DaysList fromJson(json) => DaysList(
        days: json['days'],
        hours: json['hours'] ,
      );
}

This returns all data with "hours" but in square brackets
```

Comment: Please provide a correct reproducible example.  The JSON you provided isn't valid JSON, (missing `"` before Wednesday, and that last comma is not allowed).  Furthermore you try to get `days` from your json while the field is actually called `day`.

Answer (score 0):

In your response,key 'hours' is a list of integers. So you need specify the data type as List in your class data members.

```
class DaysList {
    DaysList({
        this.day,
        this.hours,
    });

    String day;
    List<int> hours;

    factory DaysList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DaysList(
        day: json["day"],
        hours: List<int>.from(json["hours"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "day": day,
        "hours": List<dynamic>.from(hours.map((x) => x)),
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble implementing the code

Comment: What trouble are you facing? Please elaborate in more details

Comment: "_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')"

Comment: Someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<List<DaysList>> daysFuture = getDay();
Future<List<DaysList>> getDay() async {
  const url = 'address of my website';
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

  final body = json.decode(response.body);
  return json.decode(response.body);
}

class DaysList {
    DaysList({
        this.day,
        this.hours,
    });

    String day;
    List<int> hours;

    factory DaysList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DaysList(
        day: json["day"],
        hours: List<int>.from(json["hours"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "day": day,
        "hours": List<dynamic>.from(hours.map((x) => x)),
    };
```

Thank You for Your quick reply

if I put that code to VS and runs app I have feedback "  _TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List>')"

Comment: oops, actually this looks more like a comment than an answer?